# Ler atributo XML

Tags: php, xml, atributos

Estou lendo um arquivo XML com o comando `simplexml_load_file()` que possui a seguinte estrutura:

```
<nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="2.00">
    <NFe></NFe>
</nfeProc>
```

Como faço para pegar o valor do atributo `versao`?

tentei o seguinte código mas não deu certo

```
$xmlsimple=simplexml_load_file($_FILES['filexml']['tmp_name']);
echo $xmlsimple->nfeProc['versao'];
```

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66437/transformar-xml-contido-numa-string-em-json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tente assim:**

```
echo $xmlsimple->attributes()['versao'];
```

*Fonte:* [php.net](http://php.net/)

- [The SimpleXMLElement class](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.simplexmlelement.php)

Comment: Funcionou! vlw.